# asotiation rules , how do i need to convert the data for fpgrowth

Tags: r

I have data like this

```
set.seed(123)
#fake data
dat <- list()
for(i in 1:1000) dat[[i]] <- LETTERS[sample(20)] [1:sample(10)[1]]
head(dat)
```

.

```
[[1]]
[1] "M" "L" "N" "H" "F" "P" "D"

[[2]]
[1] "F" "J" "C" "A" "G" "R" "M" "O" "S"

[[3]]
[1] "Q" "C" "E" "O" "P" "D"

[[4]]
[1] "K" "C" "P" "J" "N" "O" "B" "F" "Q"

[[5]]
[1] "K" "Q" "C"

[[6]]
[1] "M" "S" "A" "O" "E" "Q"
```

I need to find all associations with `"L"`

I used to use apriori from the `arules package`

```
library(arules)
rules <- apriori(data = dat, 
                 parameter = list(supp = 0.01, 
                                  conf = 0.01), 
                  appearance = list(rhs="L")
                 )
rules
```

And it works great, but at some point it turned out to be too slow for me. I decided to try 
`fpgrowth`  from `rCBA package`

```
library(rCBA)
dat2 <- as(dat,"transactions")

rules <- rCBA::fpgrowth(dat2, support=0.01, 
                        confidence=0.01,
                        consequent="L")
```

but i get an error

```
2020-06-20 08:09:35 rCBA: initialized
2020-06-20 08:09:36 rCBA: data 1000x20
     took: 1.21  s
����. 20, 2020 8:09:36 �� cz.jkuchar.rcba.fpg.FPGrowth run
INFO: FPG: start
java.lang.NullPointerException
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
    at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:254)
    at cz.jkuchar.rcba.rules.Tuple.getCopy(Tuple.java:41)
    at cz.jkuchar.rcba.fpg.FPGrowth.insert(FPGrowth.java:304)
    at cz.jkuchar.rcba.fpg.FPGrowth.lambda$buildTree$0(FPGrowth.java:62)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at cz.jkuchar.rcba.fpg.FPGrowth.buildTree(FPGrowth.java:59)
    at cz.jkuchar.rcba.fpg.FPGrowth.run(FPGrowth.java:125)
    at cz.jkuchar.rcba.fpg.FPGrowth.run(FPGrowth.java:99)
    at cz.jkuchar.rcba.r.RPruning.fpgrowth(RPruning.java:204)
```

while the example from the `rCBA package` works fine for me..
I understand that i need to convert my data differently, but I don’t know how..
Thanks you

**UPD=======for==MarBlo===============**
please give a more complete answer, I do not understand how to use it

```
dat[[1]]
[1] "M" "L" "N" "H" "F" "P" "D"
```

.

```
DAT2 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,dat)

DAT2[1,]
 c..M....F....Q....K....K....M....O....E....O....N..
1                                                   M
  c..L....J....C....C....Q....S....D....I....H....O..
1                                                   L
  c..N....C....E....P....C....A....O....T....J....L..
1                                                   N
  c..H....A....O....J....K....O....D....G....B....F..
1                                                   H
  c..F....G....P....N....Q....E....O....C....R....M..
1                                                   F
  c..P....R....D....O....C....Q....D....Q....L....S..
1                                                   P
  c..D....M....Q....B....K....M....O....R....C....G..
1                                                   D
  c..M....O....C....F....Q....S....D....A....T....C..
1                                                   M
  c..L....S....E....Q....C....A....O....K....O....T..
1                                                   L
  c..N....F....O....K....K....O....D....P....H....K..
1                                                   N
```

Comment: Could it be that a data frame is needed?

Comment: yes, it is likely, but I don’t know how to convert it

Comment: You can do `do.call(rbind.data.frame,dat)` and give meaningful names to the cols.

Comment: @mrT A better way to make such a DF based on your list is maybe with the help of `stringi`. You could transfer your list into a matrix `mat <- stringi::stri_list2matrix(dat)` with dimensions of `10 1000` . If you tranpose this matrix it will give you 1000 rows with 1 to 10 values per row. Where the list element is shorter than 10, NA's are filled. You can then bring this into a DF like so `mat_df <- data.frame(a=t(mat))` , a DF with 10 columns (representing for each list element) and 1000 rows (representing the length your list).

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work, my real data is too large, maybe there is a solution with sparse matrices?